# Adding "..." to end of long string

Tags: jquery, string

I have a text in a h2 tag that I'm limiting its character count with by:

```
$(function() {
  $('h2.questionTitle a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.text( $this.text().slice(0,80);        
  });
});
```

However, I also want to modify the code so that if the character count was sliced at 80 chars, add "..." to the end of it.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('h2').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.text().length > 80) {

        $this.text($this.text().slice(0, 80) + '...');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yGqSK/

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('h2.questionTitle a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();

    if (text.length > 80) {
      $this.text(text.slice(0, 80) + "...");
    }
  });
});
```

Note that doing this in JavaScript is probably the wrong approach (unless you are writing a Greasemonkey script).  You should perform this kind of data mutation when outputting the page content.